# Intellisense (code completion aid) in WebStorm on import paths for Project with Vue CLI 3 is not working for Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, webstorm, vue-cli-3, webpack.config.js

I created recently a project using Vue CLI 3 and was trying to get import paths through intellisense like:

```
import Dashboard from '@/views/Dashboard.vue'
```

and unless it is an npm package WebStorm didn't offer me path completion, like if write `@/` it should list all the folders or files under alias `@`
this is I believe due to missing webpack.config.js

Answer (score 2):

Go to: Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | webpack
in Webstorm, choose this file `/choose/directory/to/current/project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js` as your `webpack configuration file` and click *Apply*

now navigate to your project and try to complete an import path, you should get intellisens